# how to save a password in a file of configuration in python

Tags: python, encoding, passwords, app-config, pygtk

I'm writing an applet in python for gnome2 that checks for new emails in gmail.

Actually i'm saving the pass of gmail in a file .config using an encoding base-64. and then decoding the pass everytime i need it.

is this secure?? it's a better way to store a password??

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not secure. Instead, you should use the Gnome keyring service, or whatever the current system offers, to store passwords.

See the [keyring](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring) package for a Python interface to such services:

```
import keyring

keyring.set_password('your_application_name', username, password)
```

`keyring` will store your password in the most secure keyring available, use `get_password('your_application_name', username)` to retrieve it again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Martijn.. just one more thing. With this method, I only have to set the password once? whats happen when i reboot the pc?

Comment: @Matias: it is stored, so it can be retrieved after a reboot.